# Perform maven release on jenkins fails cause of locked svn files

Tags: svn, maven, jenkins

I have a Multi-Module-Maven build job on jenkins. Jenkins is running on win2008 Server. A jenkins-slave, which does the work, is also running on a win2008 Server.
Perform maven release on jenkins fails cause of locked svn files:

```
The svn command failed.
Command output:
svn: E155004: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155004: Working copy 'C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\MavenDemoDeploy' locked.
svn: E155004: 'C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\MavenDemoDeploy' is already locked.
```

If I make the initial checkout and maven release build on command-line everything works fine.
If I make the release build on jenkins for a single maven module everything works fine.

**Update:**
I configured the release-plugin to use the svnkit, so it is the same client as jenkins use to checkout. I also configured preparationGoals to make a 'svn cleanup' (the cleanup works) without any success.

Comment: Do you have antivirus software on the slave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a workaround. I have configured the property commitByProject for the release-plugin. That solves the problem.
But in my opinion here is still a bug in jenkins and it should work without this parameter also.

Answer (score 0):

If a working copy is locked it means an other client is accessing the working copy in parallel which will never work. In your case i assume your slave is accessing the working copy.

Comment: I think the slave does the whole work. Checkout, running release-plugin. For single module project it works.

Comment: Yes, I have antivirus, but the mentioned folders are excluded.

Comment: The svn properties of the folder says that there is no lock.

Comment: The properties are not related. If a working copy is access in parallel you can see that a `svn status -R` will print out an `L` but this is only seeable in a small amount of time.

Comment: I configured the release-plugin to use the svnkit, so it is the same client as jenkins use to checkout. Now I get 
svn: E155000: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155000: No write-lock in 'C:\Users\myuser\workspace\MavenDemoDeploy\Module1' I tried property waitBeforeTagging without success. I also tried useEditMode without any success.